# Задний фон selector убрать (android)

Tags: android, xml

У меня есть простое меню где я использую `selector`. Но в этом `selector` появляется черный задний фон, я уже много всего перепробовал но так и не понял как сделать его прозрачным.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже мои стили:

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/getbonusClick"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_corner_tot_left"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/cart_icon_time" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/getBonus"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:text="Получить \n бонусы"
                            android:textColor="#fff" />
                    </LinearLayout>
```

`shape_corner_tot_left`

```
    <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-1dp" android:bottom="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ababb2" />

            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                 android:bottomLeftRadius="0dip"
                 android:topLeftRadius="10dip"
                 android:topRightRadius="0.1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно в `shape_corner_tot_left` во внутрь `<shape>` добавить `<solid android:color="#00000000" />`, а лучше `<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />`.
Соответственно фон у `LinearLayout` станет прозрачным с указанной границей.

Comment: спасибо, работает!